# BAD : need suggest on selenium using radio button select.have three radio buttons.need to select appropriate.but getting error

Tags: java, selenium, radio-button

I'm working on a web portal in which we can select voucher type from three radio buttons. It is not working: I am getting an error.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Vouchertest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            Logger log = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");
        driver.get("url");
            log.debug("entring username");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserName']")).sendKeys("xoxo");
            log.debug("entering password");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Password']")).sendKeys("Password123");
            log.debug("Clicking login");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='loginForm']/form/div[4]/div/input")).click();
        log.debug("Clicking voucher");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/nav/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
        log.debug("Clicking create_voucher");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/a[1]")).click();
        **log.debug("Clicking voucher_type");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='card']")).click();

    }

}
```

here is the html code for that:

```
<input id="VoucherType" type="radio" value="Corporate" name="VoucherType">
<label for="Corporate_Certificate">Corporate Certificate</label>
<input id="VoucherType" type="radio" value="Card" name="VoucherType">
<label for="Gift_Card">Gift Card</label>
<input id="VoucherType" type="radio" value="Adv" name="VoucherType">
<label for="Advanced_Payment">Advanced Payment</label>
```

here is the trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[value='card']"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.12 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML code "Card" begins with the capital letter, while in your Java code it's written like this: "input[value='card']"

Answer (score 1):

One issue I can see immediately in your css selector is in the html code you have the value as **Card** (C is upper case) but in the locator you are passing the value in simple case **card**

Please try out the following locators :

Css selector : `input[value='Card']`

Xpath : `//input[@value='Card']`

If this does not wok either check if you are having these radio buttons inside an iframe. If so you have to switch to the iframe first.

Comment: thank u so much both of u . its working . i just could not see that silly mistake.